# pdfscreen equation label incorrectly displayed

Tags: equations, labels, pdfscreen

The equation referencing label in the slide using pdfscreen package does not display as usual, instead of Eqn (2), it displayed as Eqn (2equation.0.2) and so on.... can anyone help? Thank you.

```
\RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{pause}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl} % rm
\linespread{1.0}        % Palatino needs more leading
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % ss
\usepackage{courier} % tt
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\normalfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
%\RequirePackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{vwcol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}
\usepackage{setspace}  %for {\setstretch{1.0}  }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[pdftex,screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}
\margins{0.25in}{0.25in}{0.25in}{0.25in} %left,right,top,bot
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bottombuttons
\screensize{6.25in}{8in}  % 8 in for slide; 9 in for printing
\notesname{Notes:}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\overlay{overlay1}

\begin{slide}\large\color{black}
\begin{equation}
\label{6_2} q_u = qN_qS_qd_q + \frac{1}{2}\gamma B N_\gamma
S_\gamma d_\gamma
\end{equation}

\underline{Solution}:

Given that $\phi = 39^o$ in the absence of any other experimental data, for minimum ult. dynamic bearing capacity
\[ \phi_{dy} = \phi - 2^o = 39 - 2 = 37^o \]

From eqn (\ref{6_2})
\begin{eqnarray*}
q_u &=& qN_qS_qd_q + \frac{1}{2}\gamma B N_\gamma S_\gamma d_\gamma \\
q &=& \gamma D_f = (18)(1) = 18\;\text{kN/m}^2
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As long as you do not provide any code no one will know how you made this or be able to help.

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to rely on a package that has not been updated since 2000! Move to `beamer` instead

Comment: BTW it seems to work if you remove `\RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease}`, though I had to remove `pause` as well as it is not distributed with TeXLive.

Comment: Yes, it works when \RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease} is removed, but then the slide's \overlay{overlay1} would cause the overlay1 to appear only half at the bottom of the slide.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fix

```
% \RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{pause}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl} % rm
\linespread{1.0}        % Palatino needs more leading
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % ss
\usepackage{courier} % tt
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\normalfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
%\RequirePackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{vwcol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}
\usepackage{setspace}  %for {\setstretch{1.0}  }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[pdftex,screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}
\margins{0.25in}{0.25in}{0.25in}{0.25in} %left,right,top,bot
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bottombuttons
\screensize{6.25in}{8in}  % 8 in for slide; 9 in for printing
\notesname{Notes:}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*\@Overlay@Hook{\put(\strip@pt\@tempdima,\strip@pt\@tempdima)}
{\put(\strip@pt\@tempdima,\strip@pt\dimexpr.5\paperheight)}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \overlay{overlay1}
    
    \begin{slide}\large\color{black}
        \begin{equation}
            \label{6_2} q_u = qN_qS_qd_q + \frac{1}{2}\gamma B N_\gamma
            S_\gamma d_\gamma
        \end{equation}
        
        \underline{Solution}:
        
        Given that $\phi = 39^o$ in the absence of any other experimental data, for minimum ult. dynamic bearing capacity
        \[ \phi_{dy} = \phi - 2^o = 39 - 2 = 37^o \]
        
        From eqn (\ref{6_2})
        \begin{eqnarray*}
            q_u &=& qN_qS_qd_q + \frac{1}{2}\gamma B N_\gamma S_\gamma d_\gamma \\
            q &=& \gamma D_f = (18)(1) = 18\;\text{kN/m}^2
        \end{eqnarray*}
        
    \end{slide}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]